# vb 2010 clear richtextbox within a thread

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, richtextbox

I am trying to clear a RichTextBox within a thread, but am getting an "invalidOperationException was unhandled" error. I am using the `RichTextbox.clear` command. can someone help with this error?

Comment: Are you using Invoke? [How to: Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to Invoke the clear:

```
RichTextBox1.BeginInvoke(Sub() RichTextBox1.Clear)
```

Comment: Will that work in VB 2010? (in the title)...I can't remember when various features were introduced...